# some questions about GNU makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu

i was wondering if anyone have sometime to answer some questions about GNU makefiles...

1. how to create a directory if it doesn't exists ("./obj") for output?
2. i have one makefile, but i got 2 build methods "Debug" and "Release", can i have both in 1 makefile and how to tell it which one to build?
3. ive been using Code::Blocks which builds only changed files, but my makefile builds them everytime i call make command, without touching any files. how can i make it build changed files only?

here is my current makefile

```
OBJPATH=./obj
COMPILER=gcc

Output: main.o Base64.o
 $(COMPILER) -o Output.exe $(OBJPATH)/main.o $(OBJPATH)/Base64.o
 strip Output.exe

main.o: main.c main.h
 $(COMPILER) -c main.c -o $(OBJPATH)/main.o

Base64.o: Base64.c Base64.h
 $(COMPILER) -c Base64.c -o $(OBJPATH)/Base64.o
```

thanks.

Comment: Which targets does it build when you've changed nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, you can put a fake target before any of the others, along the lines of:

```
preamble:
    -mkdir obj

main.o: preamble main.c
    blah blah blah
```

That will automatically execute everything in the preamble (you have to make it the first dependency in every rule) before it builds anything else. The `-` at the start of the `mkdir` ignores failures if, for example, the directory already exists.

For the second question, you can provide something like:

```
all: debug release

debug: blah blah blah

release: blah blah blah
```

and actually put the debug and release code in *separate* subdirectories. That way, you can build either with `make release` or `make debug` and build them *both* with `make all`.

Third question: Your makefile builds every time because the rules tell it to. For example, `Output: main.o Base64.o` will always try to build since `Output` never exists (the correct target seems to be `Output.exe`).

Similarly your object file rules will always execute since neither `main.o` nor `Base64.o` are updated by their statements (they update the files in the `obj` directory instead).

You may be able to fix that case by making the target `$(OBJPATH)/main.o` but, to be honest, I don't usually worry about separating objects and executables into separate directories. I tend to just lump them all into one directory and let `make -clean` clean them up.

---

So the makefile I would start with would be:

```
COMPILER=gcc

# Meta rules

all: release debug

release: Output.exe

debug: Output-d.exe

# Release stuff

Output.exe: main.o Base64.o
    $(COMPILER) -o Output.exe main.o Base64.o
    strip Output.exe

main.o: main.c main.h
    $(COMPILER) -c main.c -o main.o

Base64.o: Base64.c Base64.h
    $(COMPILER) -c Base64.c -o Base64.o

# Debug stuff

Output-d.exe: main-d.o Base64-d.o
    $(COMPILER) -g -o Output-d.exe main-d.o Base64-d.o

main-d.o: main.c main.h
    $(COMPILER) -g -DDEBUG -c main.c -o main-d.o

Base64-d.o: Base64.c Base64.h
    $(COMPILER) -g -DDEBUG -c Base64.c -o Base64-d.o
```

---

In response to your comment question:

> Is there anyway I can re-set a variable based on the Target Selected? for example if selected release OBJPATH will be "./obj/Release" if selected debug OBJPATH = "./obj/Debug"?

GNU Make may be more powerful than the ones I'm used to but you can do that by setting an environment variable then re-running make as per the following:

```
all: release debug

release:
        ( export zzvar=release ; $(MAKE) zz_Output.exe )

debug:
        ( export zzvar=debug ; $(MAKE) zz_Output-d.exe )

zz_Output.exe:
        echo $(zzvar)
        touch zz_Output.exe

zz_Output-d.exe: zz_main-d.o zz_Base64-d.o
        echo $(zzvar)
        touch zz_Output-d.exe
```

which outputs:

```
( export zzvar=release ; make zz_Output.exe )
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pax'
echo release
release                                             <==
touch zz_Output.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pax'

( export zzvar=debug ; make zz_Output-d.exe )
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pax'
echo debug
debug                                               <==
touch zz_Output-d.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pax'
```

You can see the two separate variables marked with `<==` above.

As I said, there's probably an easier way to do it with GNU Make but that'll get you started.

Comment: first and second fixed, thanks, but third, i dont really get it, can u show me by example in the makefile i supplied? thanks

Comment: thank you, i got it now, just one last thing (sorry) is there anyway i can re-set a variable based on the Target Selected? for example if selected release OBJPATH will be "./obj/Release" if selected debug OBJPATH = "./obj/Debug" ?

Answer (score 1):

> how to create a directory if it doesn't exists ("./obj") for output?

```
rm -Rf ./obj && mkdir ./obj
```

> i have one makefile, but i got 2 build methods "Debug" and "Release", can i have both in 1 makefile and how to tell it which one to build?

You can have multiple top level build targets. `Output` in your makefile is a top level target. Make two. One called "Debug" and the other "Release". You can then say `make Debug` for the debug build and `make Release` for the release build.

> ive been using Code::Blocks which builds only changed files, but my makefile builds them everytime i call make command, without touching any files. how can i make it build changed files only?

I haven't used `Code::Blocks` (I don't know what it is) but if your Makefiles are written properly (i.e. with dependencies properly specified), it will only rebuild the required targets.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment question:

> Is there anyway I can re-set a variable based on the Target Selected?
>   for example if selected release OBJPATH will be "./obj/Release" if
>   selected debug OBJPATH = "./obj/Debug"?

Here is how you do it without recursion:

```
COMPILER=gcc

release: OBJPATH = obj
release: Output.exe

debug: OBJPATH = obj-dbg
debug: Outputd.exe

Output%.exe: main.o Base64.o
 $(COMPILER) -o $@ $(OBJPATH)/main.o $(OBJPATH)/Base64.o
 strip $@

main.o: main.c main.h
 $(COMPILER) -c main.c -o $(OBJPATH)/main.o

Base64.o: Base64.c Base64.h
 $(COMPILER) -c Base64.c -o $(OBJPATH)/Base64.o
```